# Default file extension of the executable created by g++ under Cygwin vs Linux

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, cygwin, g++, portability

I've done most of my work on VisualStudio and don't have much experience with gcc or g++. When I tried to compile a (ex. aprogram.cpp) this morning on my pc using cygwin, I got (aprogram.exe) when I tried to compile the same thing on my Ubuntu box I got (aprogram) w/o any extension. I am just wondering if someone be kind enough to tell me why. This question is just out of curiosity. :)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
(from Jimmy's comment) 
g++ under Cygwin defaults to .exe

Comment: Simple answer about g++.

Comment: Seriously, make your title descriptive, like "why is there no extension in the file name of g++' output?"

Comment: Thanks. But its fixed again - hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 18):

That's easy: on UNIX, [you don't need no steenkin' extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges).  In fact, an "extension" like .c is just a convenient naming convention; unlike Windows, the file system sees the file name as one string, .c and all.

For a *really* good time, compile a C program with no `-o` flag at all.  Your executable will still show up --- named the default name for executables: `a.out`.

Comment: it also uses the info after the '.' to put print pretty colors in your shell.

Comment: MS-DOS actually stored file names as an 8 character name and a 3 character extension. Windows 95 and up treated the file name as one long string. Unfortunately, old habits can be hard to break. You can still see people using *.* to mean all files when the correct wildcard is *

Comment: Almost - even on NTFS, a final "." on a filename is ignored/removed (in the same way that case is ignored), for no discernable good reason.

Comment: No, a final period is *not* removed on NTFS. It is removed by the Windows shell (explorer.exe) for no good reason - NTFS as such (i.e. the Microsoft NTFS driver and all alternatives,including ntfs-3g) does not remove anything. Please be clearer.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty fun to mess with NTFS. For example, you can put on a Linux LiveCD, write files called for example `NUL`, and it will be off-limits to Windows :) Also, you can have mixed upper- and lower-case on NTFS.

Answer (score 13):

It's just a naming convention.
On Unix/Linux, executables don't have an extension, just an executable bit.

Answer (score 7):

.exe is a windows thing.  Unix doesn't care about extensions.  Executability is based on metadata on the file as well as the file's contents.  g++ through cygwin is not **really** a windows app, so it carries its unix roots with it.

Comment: IIRC cygwin g++ actually defaults to .exe extensions, including the default 'a.exe' if no -o is given

Answer (score 4):

If you were wondering how to execute the program on UNIX, simply navigate to the folder with your program you wish to execute (aprogram) and type

```
./aprogram
```

This will tell the shell you wish to execute 'aprogram' in the current directory.

Answer (score 4):

Executables have no extension in the unix world, because they are meant to be executed in the shell. Imagine the following:

```
cat.bin file.txt | less.bin
```

That's ugly! Unix makes use of so-called magic bytes at the start of each file to detect the file-type. For the default binary format, called ELF, there is a 4 byte word `7f 45 4c 46` at the start. That's not possible for all file formats. Consider C code or Java code. They can both start with comments, and can be made look exactly the same. So you still have to use file-name extensions, and it's a good thing when used where it's appropriate.

Comment: Well, you don't need to type .exe in Windows either... Good point on the ELF header though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output to have an .exe extension then just use the -o flag to do so (e.g. -o aprogram.exe). It will work just fine under linux either way.

The ability to execute a program under linux is based on the file's permissions (see [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)). Execute permissions will be automatically set by gcc/g++.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, just name them `.elf`. And if you're not sure what file type they are, execute:

```
$ file MyFile
```

This will tell you what are the contents of the file, and you can pick a name this way, but it's not necessary - just cosmetic if you have been used to extensions all life.

Answer (score 1):

ls /bin
There are lot's of programs and all of them without extension :)

ls -l /bin
you will see that all of them has +x flag to mark them as an executable.