# How to change the name of the output binary to not be a.out with CMake?

Tags: cmake

Where would I go within CMakeLists.txt in order to change the name of the generated file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cmake executable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395517/cmake-executable-name)

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/examples/ -> add_executable (helloDemo demo.cxx demo_b.cxx)  
helloDemo is the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(demo)

add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
```

This CMakeLists.txt compiles a hello.cpp file to an executable named hello. You can name the executable anything by using the `add_executable` statement.

```
add_executable(<executable-name> <source1> <source2> ...)
```

Answer (score 27):

For an executable target see target properties [OUTPUT_NAME](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) and [SUFFIX](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/SUFFIX.html). The actual output name if a combination of `OUTPUT_NAME`.`SUFFIX` with

- `OUTPUT_NAME` defaulting to the target's name
- `SUFFIX` defaulting to

  - whatever is defined in [CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX.html) for your platform (e.g. `.exe` on Windows platforms)
  - if the suffix is empty the compiler might add an extension (see [Default file extension of the executable created by g++ under Cygwin vs Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359707/default-file-extension-of-the-executable-created-by-g-under-cygwin-vs-linux))

So the following example would override both defaults:

```
add_executable(a ...)
set_target_properties(
    a 
    PROPERTIES 
        OUTPUT_NAME "myname"
        SUFFIX ".myext"
)
```

Would generate `myname.myext` for target `a`.

For more details e.g. take a look at [adding program suffix](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/adding-program-suffix-td7583549.html).

Comment: This is the answer I needed. I needed to know how to set the suffix so I could get the same file output for both windows and linux. This does that. Thanks!