# VisualStudio Cmake IoT target crosscompilation .exe is added to the program name

Tags: c, visual-studio, cmake, embedded

I am trying to use Visual Studio (my boss uses it) for the uC programmming.

Generally speaking everything is relatively fine, but VS always adds `.exe` to the program name (it should be `.elf`).

```
add_executable("GC${BOARD_NAME}-FW.elf" ${SOURCES} ${INCLUDE_FILES} ${ASM_FILES})
```

but in VS I always have (sorry for the picture - but it is an IDE)

[image]

How can I force the VS to use the correct filename?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the name of the output binary to not be a.out with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904273/how-to-change-the-name-of-the-output-binary-to-not-be-a-out-with-cmake) You should be able to modify the `SUFFIX` property to get the file extension you desire.

Comment: @squareskittles yes it did the job!!! Post as the answer I will accept it instantly.

Comment: And, of course, no feedback on whether my suggestion worked or not.

Comment: Thanks for the update.